# Drop down list to select a table and an additional drop down list to filter

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I want to use 2 drop down lists on the same page, one of them to select the table from the Db and the other to filter the selected table. I think this is very basic but I am new in PHP and SQL. I have no problem to use a submit to filter the table by group but I don't know where assign to `$table` variable the  `$_POST['tables']` value.

Here is the relevant part of my code, :

```
 $table=table_name;

 if(isset($_POST['tables'])) { 

     $table=$_POST['tables'];

 }

 //filtering by group
    if(true===isset($_POST['value'])) { 
          if($_POST['value'] == 'All') { 
             // query to get all records 
              $query = "SELECT * FROM $table";   
          } else {   
            // filter groups
            $value=$_POST['value'];
            $query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE Grupo='$value'";   
          }
     } else {   
          // the first time the page is loaded 

          $query = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY Grupo ASC";   
     }

     $sql = mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear. From what I understand, you need to show all the tables on one drop down list and on the other, you want to show all the columns. Am I getting you correct?

Comment: the first drop down list shows the tables and the second one is for filter the selected table on the first drop down list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function sortResult(str)
{
  var e = document.getElementById("firstDrop");
  var str1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var e = document.getElementById("secondDrop");
  var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","results.php?q="+str+"&t="+str1,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<!--database name-->
<select name="tablename" id="firstDrop">
            <option selected='selected' value="yourdatabasename1">DB1</option>
            <option value="yourdatabasename2">DB2</option>
</select>
<!--sort by what-->
<select name="sortby" id="secondDrop">
            <option selected='selected' value="slno">slno</option>
            <option value="name">name</option>
            <option value="author">author</option>
</select>
<button id="sub" onclick="sortResult()">CLICK</button>

<br><br>
<div id="result"><b>Results will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

results.php

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['q'];
$t = $_GET['t'];

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','yourusername','password','database');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_select_db($con,"database");
$sql="SELECT * FROM ".$t." ORDER BY ".$q;

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Author</th>
<th>ID</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" .$row['name']. "</td>";
  echo "<td>" .$row['author'] ."</td>";
  echo "<td>" .$row['slno']. "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
echo $t;
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

modify accordingly.

Comment: this is... thorough but a bit hard to use :p

Comment: Thanks it works! is it possible to show the complete table the first time you open the page?

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo...

```
if(isset($_POST['tables'])) { 
    $tabla=$_POST['tables'];
}
```

change to

```
if(isset($_POST['tables'])) { 
    $table=$_POST['tables'];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Correct your query syntax--

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM '".$table."'";


$query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE Grupo='$value'";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM '".$table."' WHERE Grupo='".$value."'";
```

and

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM '".$table."' ORDER BY Grupo";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM '".$table."' ORDER BY Grupo";
```

Comment: The query sintax is good, when i select a table from the dropdown list the data is shown correctly but when i select the group from the second list, it always filters the data from the default table.

Comment: this does not make any sense. you do not put quotes around table names in sql.